# reformat an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array ( 
    [0] => Chrome 35 (Lin) 
    [1] => Chrome 35 (Unk) 
    [2] => Chrome 35 (Unk) 
    [3] => Chrome 18 (Lin) 
    [4] )
```

And I want to get a count of each unique value like this:

```
[["Chrome 35 (lin)",1],["Chrome 35 (Unk)",2],["firefox",20]]
```

I really have no idea on how to achieve this, but this format is totally unknown to me.

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$counts = array_count_values($values);
$result = array_map(null, array_keys($counts), $counts);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$a = array("Chrome 35 (Lin)","Chrome 35 (Unk)", "Chrome 35 (Unk)", "Chrome 18 (Lin)", "Chrome 18 (Lin)", "Chrome 18 (Lin)", "Chrome 18 (Lin)", "Chrome 18 (Lin)");
$vals = array_count_values($a);
foreach($vals as $k=>$v){
    $c .= '["'.$k.'", '.$v.']'; 
}
echo "[".$c."]";
```